# Yahoo doesn't accept emails i send to it

Tags: email, postfix-mta, yahoo-mail

i am writing a sendmail module to email some things to my site users.
for testing it i use my own email at yahoo to receive this email.
but something woeful happened. about 1200 sent to my email address at yahoo at a moment and yahoo sent all of them to spam box.
now i can't send any email to  yahoo addresses and my server gives me this message in mailq:

> delivery temporarily suspended: host g.mx.mail.yahoo.com[98.137.54.238] refused to talk to me...

how can i solve this problem?? many users of my site have yahoo email address.

my server uses postfix.
thanks for helping .

Comment: Well... sending the same message 1200 times might have triggered something ಠ_ಠ

Comment: i don't want to do something bad.i wanted to send a message to my site users but i put my email to test it and this happend :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many mail servers will block an unrecognized mail server that tries to send a lot of messages at once. It's a security feature built into most of them, and be thankful for it too; anyone with a sendmail daemon could flood your inbox with 1200+ spam messages if the server weren't checking.

Many times you will have to wait 24 hours before the server lets you back in again. Sometimes even a week; it's never certain.

I'd suggest building a message queueing system into your program (or, if there's an option for it, into your sendmail daemon) to limit to 50 messages per hour per receiving host, and test the water.

Answer (score 1):

Did you send 1200 emails to one account all at once? If so, you were probably blocked for abuse. It may be temporary however, if you've been blacklisted you should probably [contact Yahoo!](http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/mail/).